# how to copy data to data table in linq step by step process in linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am fresher in linq,So please give me the link or write step by step procedure to fill data table in linq.

here is the code

```
var Sql = from t1 in pitbull.ACC_APP1_QuickViews.AsEnumerable()
          join t2 in pitbull.OCC_VehicleGroups.AsEnumerable() 
          on t1.VehicleId equals t2.VehicleID
          select new
          {
            t1.Lat,
            t1.Lon,
            t1.Timestamp_GPS,
            t1.Speed,
            t1.Location,
            t1.Status,
            t1.VehicleRegNo,
            t1.VehicleId,
            t2.VGID,
            t2.VGName
            };
DataTable dt = new DataTable();enter code here
dt=Sql.copytodatatable();

//copy to datatable not support.Improve question   Permalink
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are creating a anonymous type using `select new{ }` to hold the Field objects. Try this:

```
var Sql = from t1 in pitbull.ACC_APP1_QuickViews.AsEnumerable()
          join t2 in pitbull.OCC_VehicleGroups.AsEnumerable() 
          on t1.VehicleId equals t2.VehicleID
          select t2;

DataTable dt = Sql.copytodatatable();
```

Comment: i try this but there is an exception.   The type 'ACC_APP1_QuickView' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ACC_APP1_QuickView' to 'System.Data.DataRow'